# Using HTML link in PostgreSQL procedure

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use an HTML link in PostgreSQL procedure along with some local variable.  However, I am getting syntax errors reguarding parenthesis.  Something like

```
  '<a href="http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q='my_variable'" target=\"_blank\">' my_variable '</a>'
```

However, I am getting syntax errors.  I am thinking it has to do with escape characters.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Derek

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
 '<a href="http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=''my_variable''" target=\"_blank\">' || my_variable || '</a>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I see you put the escape \ before the double-quote in target.  Do I need to do the same for the ones in href?

Comment: Yes.  But, I also had to use || to concatenate strings with the variables.